# Minimal XML library for C++?

Tags: c++, c, xml

What XML libraries are out there, which are minimal, easy to use, come with little dependencies (ideally none), can be linked statically and come with a liberal license? So far, I've been a pretty happy user of [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/), but I'm curious what alternatives I have missed so far.

Comment: Would you like to exclude a Windows-only library?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a portable library if possible, otherwise, I still have no solution left for Linux :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [rapidxml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/).  It's an order of magnitude smaller than tinyxml, and doesn't choke on doctypes like tinyxml does.

If you need entity support or anything advanced, forget about static linking and use expat or libxml2.

Answer (score 8):

[expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) is a very fast C XML parser (although a C++ wrapper exists) that's widely used in many open-source projects. If I remember correctly, it has very few dependencies, and it's licensed under the very liberal MIT License.

Comment: Sounds good, gotta take a look at it, especially how difficult it is to build it.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW there is also a version of TinyXML with a more C++-like interface, called [ticpp](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/).

Answer (score 0):

There's one called `libxml2`.

There's also a Windows-only solution, a COM library that's part of the O/S, called `msxml`.

Answer (score 0):

In "[what’s the easiest way to generate xml in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303371/whats-the-easiest-way-to-generate-xml-in-c)" I wrote [a comment that lists a few C++ XML libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303371/whats-the-easiest-way-to-generate-xml-in-c#303724)

[TinyXML++ (ticpp)](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/) was, IMHO, the most appropriate for a small, easy to use XML library in C++.