# Output in SVG format

Tags: c++, svg

Does anyone have examples of how to output in SVG format? I did a search on the boards and didn't get anything to return.

My output contest numbers.

I'd like to write string of numbers, like 1,2,3 on a middle of page.

Comment: Here is the spec for SVG 1.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/ You can use a file stream to output into a file. There is no support for SVG processing in the standard library.

Comment: Why not [Googling it first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)? Outputting text with SVG is extremely simple.

Comment: I googling it for hour but i still not find any solutions to my problem :(

There is no support for SVG processing but my profesor still told us to do this as a home work :/ No idea what i'll do with this.

Comment: There's plenty of learning SVG resources around such as this: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html SVG is just  XML so to output SVG in C++ there's lots of options e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303371/whats-the-easiest-way-to-generate-xml-in-c

Comment: I go for it:

<text x="15" y="45" font-size="40" fill="red">some text</text>

but it dosent work in c++

Comment: What do you mean "it does't work in C++"?  That might actually be a decent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment, just output the svg code you need in some I/O stream:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::cout << "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width='100' height='100'>\n";
    std::cout << "<text x='10' y='20'>" << a << "</text>\n";
    std::cout << "</svg>\n";
}
```

Then compile:

```
$ g++ a.cpp
```

and run:

```
$ a.out > myfile.svg
```

Comment: But, still, your question is rather unclear...

Comment: There would be a lot less escaping if you used single-quote marks for the attributes: `"<text x='10' y='20'>A</text>\n"`

Comment: @Martin Bonner true ! Thanks, I didn't actually notice single quotes were possible.

Comment: but could i use variable instead of string? 

"<text x='10' y='20'> VARIABLE </text>\n"

Comment: Sure. I edited answer.

Comment: Wow i thanks you a lot :)
I'm really a beginner in c++
You help me a lot and i'm sorry if my instructions were unclear.

Comment: You're welcome, remember you can also upvote an answer ;-)